# Can't run dotnet test with FullyQualifiedName using TextFixture

Tags: .net, nunit

I can't run dotnet test comand using FullyQualifiedName

```
        namespace TestNameSpace
        {
            [TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
            [TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]

            public class TestClass
        {
        public TestClass(Platform platform)
            : base(platform)
        {
        }
        [Test]
        public void SomeTest()
        {}
        }
        }
```

I tried a lot of combinations like

```
FullyQualifiedName= TestNameSpace.Platform.Android.TestClass.SomeTest 
FullyQualifiedName=~ TestNameSpace.Platform.Android.TestClass.SomeTest 
FullyQualifiedName=~ TestNameSpace.TestClass.SomeTest & cat = Platform.iOS
FullyQualifiedName=~ TestNameSpace.TestClass.SomeTest & cat == Platform.iOS 
FullyQualifiedName=~ TestNameSpace.TestClass.SomeTest & TestCategory == Platform.iOS
```

but they didn't work and I didn't get any interesting errors to understand. Don't get the gist of how to use TextFixture correctly, I use a usual console, not from nUnit

Could someone say how to use TextFixture, particularly in my case (Platform.Android or Platform.iOS) for FullyQualifiedName? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you run your tests? There are many ways to run NUnit tests and the answer will be different depending on how you do it. For example... nunit-console? vs test window? some third party runner? code you have written yourself? (You should edit your question rather than replying in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

As @charlie comments, it all depends on the runner you choose.  It looks like you might be using `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName= TestNameSpace.Platform.Android.TestClass.SomeTest` , or perhaps vstest.  However, both of these are dependent on the C# definition of a FullyQualifiedName, and as you have a parametrized fixture, your FQN looks like `TestNameSpace.TestClass(Android).SomeTest`. And, the parentheses here is not something that the Microsoft test runner will accept.

However, you could use the NUnit.Where statement which is supported by the NUnit3TestAdapter, and which forwards this statement to the NUnit.Engine, see https://blog.prokrams.com/2019/12/16/nunit3-filter-dotnet/ for details, but since you have a parametrized fixture, there is a bug here that blocks the parentheses, that one is in the token parser in the adapter though. I'll add a bug [there](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues)  (or you can), so that it can be fixed.

The way to go then is to use the NUnit.Console, you can install that as a dotnet tool `dotnet tool install --global NUnit.ConsoleRunner.NetCore --version 3.15.2`

Running your test then with `nunit --test=TestNameSpace.TestClass(Android).SomeTest bin/debug/net6.0/runbyfqn.dll` will result in exactly one test being run.

[image]

There is another weird thing here.  If you use Visual Studio, you can select exactly one test here, and it will be run like that.  That also uses the adapter/engine pair and we need to look into how that is passed. Whatever Visual Studio does should also be doable running dotnet test.

To be able to see more what is happening behind the scenes, you can use the dump facility of the adapter, like:
`dotnet test -- NUnit.`
You will then get a dump file under your bin/debug/net6.0/dump folder, and it will show you all the relevant names for your tests, like:
[image]